# Javascript: Why is my optimized loop slower than the more naive one

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, loops

Link to jsperf if you prefer its formatting : https://jsperf.com/test-array-vs-loop-vs-loop-optimized

I was trying an old jsperf loop vs filter, and I tried to optimize the loop by preallocating the array if a correct size and avoiding item length recalculation. Issue is it didn't run faster on my Chrome 60.

Here is the code :

```
var items = [];
var names = ['george', 'nick', 'jack', 'herodotus', 'joanne'];
for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    var obj = {
        name: names[i % 5] + '-' + i,
        age: i % 10 + 15
    };
    items.push(obj);
}

function filter_callback(item) {
    return (item.age == '18');
}

function test_filter() {
    var aged_18_filter = items.filter(filter_callback);
}

function test_loop() {
    var aged_18_loop = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].age == '18') aged_18_loop.push(items[i]);
    }
}

function test_loop_optimized() {
    var length=items.length
    var aged_18_loop = new Array(length);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (items[i].age == '18') aged_18_loop[i]=items[i];
    }
}
```

Edit : The results were about 39,281 ops/sec for normal loop, and 37,389 ops/sec for "optimized" loop. On i7 3610QM.

Comment: I dont understand what your optimization is.

Comment: Hint: `new Array(length)` has the *wrong* size if you're trying to filter, and by assigning to `aged_18_loop[i]` instead of the end of the array you're even creating a sparse array with holes. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: What results did you get, can you post them please? I don't have any Chrome 60 at hand.

Comment: Thanks, I totally see it now.  
The results were about 39,281 ops/sec for normal loop, and 37,389 ops/sec for "optimized" loop. On i7 3610QM.  
@swailem95 My last function preallocated the loop, and used "var length" instead of "items.length" in loop condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried to optimize the loop by preallocating the array if a correct size

But you failed at that. The filter result usually doesn't have the same size as the input. By not appending to the array at its end (using `push`) and assigning to the index `i` always, you even were creating a sparse array. (Given your very small sample, it didn't have a large impact at least).

A correct approach might be

```
function test_loop_optimized() {
    var length = items.length;
    // let's guess that the result will have about a fifth of the size
    var result = new Array(Math.round(length / 5));
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    while (i < length) {
        var item = items[i++];
        if (item.age == '18')
            result[j++] = item;
    }
    result.length = j; // just in case we guessed too high
    return result;
}
```

> …and avoiding item length recalculation

That's a trivial optimisation that the JS engine does figure out to apply by itself. Accessing `.length` isn't really slow actually. Unless there's something weird going on, you won't benefit from spelling this out.